# How to count pairings of cells in spreadsheet

Tags: excel

Let's say I have a spreadsheet that has two columns of data. For example:

```
A    B
1    2
2    3
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    3
2    1
```

How could I count the total number of times each pair appears in the spreadsheet.  In the example above, 1-2 should have a count of 3 (1 for 2-1, 2 for 1-2), 2-3 should have a count of 2etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that for **Excel versions >2007**, you can use the new formula [**`COUNTIFS`**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx):

[EDIT] Added the correct solution (credits to **Chris Nielsen** - see the comments)

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$12,A1,$B$1:$B$12,B1) + COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$12,B1,$B$1:$B$12,A1)
```

Comment: +1 offers a significant speed advantage over `SUMPRODUCT` in xl07 and xl0

Comment: Fails to satisfy the criteria that order is not important.  See example where 1-2 count should be 3.  Change to `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$12,A1,$B$1:$B$12,B1)+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$12,B1,$B$1:$B$12,A1)` to get correct count

Comment: Agree with Brett, will be faster.

Comment: @chrisneilsen good pick up Chris. I had focussed on the technique rather than the actual solution

Comment: @chrisneilsen: thanks. I missed that point in the OP's example

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use a SUMPROUDUCT in column C.  That would give you a count of the number of times the combination in that row is encountered.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$7=A1),--($B$1:$B$7=B1))+SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$7=B1),--($B$1:$B$7=A1))
```

Following your example this would output:

```
A   B   C
1   2   3
2   3   2
1   1   1
1   2   3
1   3   1
2   3   2
2   1   3
```

SUMPRODUCT can be tricky, you can read some good howtos here:

http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/10/excel-sumproduct-formula/

Jesse

Comment: Fails to satisfy the criteria that order is not important.  See example where 1-2 count should be 3.

Comment: Updated to account for order criteria.