# MS-Excel: COUNTA() Only IF()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a 2 column spreadsheet.

- Column A either contains an "A" or a "B"
- Column B either contains a dollar values or is blank

I want to get a total count of **dollar values** in column B only for instances **where column A has an A**

Does anyone know what the formula looks like to do that?

I have been tweaking `=counta(if())` and can't seem to get it to give me the correct result,

Thanks.

Comment: You want to use CountIf.  (This is a SuperUser question.)

Comment: This kind of question *could be* asked on superuser but please do not crosspost. If needed, your question will be migrated.

Comment: Sorry, I was hasty (and wrong about Countif) in my comment.

Comment: @JMax...feel free to move this to SuperUser if that makes better sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite similar to this case: [How to count pairings of cells in spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571244/how-to-count-pairings-of-cells-in-spreadsheet/8572564#8572564)

This is not *really* `COUNTIF` but `COUNTIFS` (with an `S`):

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$12,"A",$B$1:$B$12,"$")
```

Comment: Well, thanks @Jmax but my spreadsheet returned zero -- in other words, no count

Comment: This only works if value in Column B is exactly "$".  You could edit to =COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$12,"A",$B$1:$B$12,">0") and if I'm understanding correctly (not a given!) it should work.

Comment: @Doug Clancy, that too retuned zero results

Comment: Hang on...my bad -- it works (I just can't copy and paste correctly)