# Count the quantity of unique combinations in multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to have excel count the number of times number pairs occur in the same row regardless of their order. The following is what I'm look for. Column C will display the number of times A & B contain the same numbers, but not necessarily in the same columns (or order). Example below: 6 2 and 2 6 should be considered the same thing. Therefore the count in Column C should = 2 for both 6 2 and 2 6.

My Objective:

[image]

I tried the pivot table suggested at the following link and it successfully counted matching pairs, but for example 6 2 and 2 6 were not considered the same and the count was only 1 for each.

[This simple pivot table solution almost works](https://superuser.com/questions/462010/count-the-quantity-of-unique-combinations-of-multiple-columns-in-excel)

Thank you! They all seem to work, but the easiest solution I found was here [Quick to copy for large data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571244/how-to-count-pairings-of-cells-in-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 2):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1:B1,B:B,TRANSPOSE(A1:B1)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [solution from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/462010/count-the-quantity-of-unique-combinations-of-multiple-columns-in-excel) you posted, but use:

```
=CONCATENATE(MAX(A2:B2),MIN(A2:B2))
```

Comment: How would this handle A=B? I'm not trying to pick holes in your solution, I'm on a train without access to Excel at the moment. I had a similar idea but was worried about A=B.

Comment: @CJC, what is the maximum of 2 and 2?  it is 2 and so is the minimum.  So it would return 22.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to think of a single - formula solution using `COUNTIFS` but can't find one at the moment so here's a two formula version.

In column D `=IF(A2<B2,A2&", "&B2,B2&",  "&A2)`

In column C `=COUNTIF(D:D, D2)`

This creates a list in column D with the following logic;

```
If A < B then A goes first
If A > B then B goes first 
If A = B then B goes first but it doesn't really matter
```

The list will be a set of strings which we then count.